# Enforce orphan deletion on a dataset created by XSD

Tags: c#, xsd, dataset, delete-row, cascading-deletes

In my DataSet I have two Tables that come from and XML with XSD definition:

- Register
- Type

And a one to many Relation

```
<xs:keyref name="RegisterForeingKey" refer="myXsd:TypeKey">
  <xs:selector xpath="Register"/>
  <xs:field xpath="TypeID"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

This means that the Registers have one Type, and one Type can be referenced by many Registers.

When I delete one Register I want to clean the associated Type if it's orphan  (clean Types that have no association). Is `msdata:DeleteRule="Cascade"` the best option for this?

Can someone provide me a simple example of how to implement it on XSD?

I tried to add this to the relation

```
<xs:keyref name="RegisterForeingKey" refer="myXsd:TypeKey" msdata:DeleteRule="Cascade" msdata:EnforceConstraints="true">
  <xs:selector xpath="Register"/>
  <xs:field xpath="TypeID"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

And delete it like this `dataSrc.Tables["Register"].Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex); dataSrc.AcceptChanges();`

But it does not clean the orphans

Answer (score 0):

After reading about this matter I realized a few things, which I will let here to help others who stumble with the same difficulty as me.

- Cascade is defined by default
- Cascade only works Top to Bottom, meaning that it only works if you delete the parent, then it will automatically delete the childs associated to him
- After deleting one row `dataset.AcceptChanges()` is required, so that it detaches the rows out of the dataset

In the OP I was trying to use Cascade in the opposite direction, when deleting the last Register of one Type, remove the Type so it does not remain orphan. Cascade simply does not work that way.

Therefore my final solution is:

```
DataRow registerRow = dataSrc.Tables["Register"].Rows[rowIndex];
DataRow typeRow = registerRow.GetParentRow(dataSrc.Relations["RegisterForeingKey"]);
DataRow[] typeChilds = typeRow.GetChildRows(dataSrc.Relations["RegisterForeingKey"]);

if (typeChilds.Length > 1)
{
    // There are more Registers with the same Parent Type
    registerRow.Delete();
}
else
{
    // Last Register of this Type, delete it and the rest will be deleted by Cascade
    typeRow.Delete();
}

dataSrc.AcceptChanges();
```

Please correct me if I said something wrong, or if my solution could be improved.